# How to order wp_query by taxonomy term / custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I build a WP query with order first by a related taxonomy and secondary by post title (or custom field)?

my "tax_x" is the taxonomy with the field to order the loop
my "tax_y" limits the items, it is needed by not relevant for the order
and I have a custom_field_2 for the secondary-/sub-ordering of the post in the product cpt…

```
$product_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
            //'orderby'         => 'slug',          
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'tax_x',
                    'meta_key'     => 'custom_field_1',
                    ),
            ),

            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'tax_y',
                    'field'     => 'id',
                    'terms'     => $this_term_id
                    ),

           ) 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use order by meta_query element, you should not use orderby meta_value, you can use orderby meta_query_array_name instead.

So let's give a name to tax_x meta_query array and then use orderby that element. 
And if you additionally ordering by post title, then you need to use array of two elements as orderby value. Here is the example:

```
$product_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page'    => '-1',      
            'orderby'           => array ('tax_x_meta'=>'ASC','title'=>ASC),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'tax_x_meta'=>array(
                    'value'  => 'tax_x',
                    'key'     => 'custom_field_1',
                    ),
            ),

            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'tax_y',
                    'field'     => 'id',
                    'terms'     => $this_term_id
                    ),

           ) 
    );
}
```

The part "value'  => 'tax_x'," is unclear of course, i didn't understand what taxonomy is doing inside meta_query.

Comment: both taxonomies have the same function but not always at the same time/postition.

Comment: In the code above:
tax_x brings terms (values), linke filed values in post type. 
tax_y limits the output to one tax term.
Like I said before tax_x and tax_y  can change there function_ tax_y is for ordering and tax_x limits the loop.

When I tired out your code the meta query part stops any output in the loop :-(

Comment: no, my code was just for explanation, as an example, it can't be working code as i don't know full data structure of your products. Using 'taxonomy'  => 'tax_x' inside meta_query is completely wrong. it can't work, the best thing it can do is to be ignored by WP QUERY. meta_query is for wp_postmeta table data. but taxonomy data is stored in terms tables.